# make font weight bold for those Select Options that are enabled

Tags: html, css

I have a Select that has some Option in it. How can make `font-weight: bold` just for those options that are enabled?

Here is the sample code:

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="group1">
    <option value="2016" disabled>2016</option>
    <option value="2017" disabled>2017</option>
    <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="group2">
    <option value="2020" disabled>2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

2016, 2017, 2020 be the normal font and more grayed color (or special color code), and 2018,2019,2021 be bold. How to do that?

Note: I'm not going to add inline code for every option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `:checked` selector is most widely supported. This works for **checkboxes** and **select** lists. You can also select and style `:disabled`

However, be aware that some browsers don't support a lot of font changes inside the browser's select component. So color, weight, etc may or may not work depending on where it's viewed. **Meaning you can't count on this for important interface/user feedback.**

```css
option { 
  font-weight: bold;
}
option:checked { 
  color: red;
}
option:disabled { 
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!-- this doesn't work in Chrome when wrapped in a Select -->
<select>
   <optgroup label="group1">
     <option value="2016" disabled>2016</option>
     <option value="2017" disabled>2017</option>
     <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
     <option value="2019">2019</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="group2">
     <option value="2020" disabled>2020</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<!-- this works in Chrome -->
<optgroup label="group1">
  <option value="2016" disabled>2016</option>
  <option value="2017" disabled>2017</option>
  <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="group2">
  <option value="2020" disabled>2020</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not` selector like this:

```css
option:not(disabled) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<optgroup label="group1">
  <option value="2016" disabled>2016</option>
  <option value="2017" disabled>2017</option>
  <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="group2">
  <option value="2020" disabled>2020</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
option:checked { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: Head's up that's only going to bold the selected option. Not all options != disabled

Answer (score 0):

You should use an input like checkboxes then you can use the :checked css state

The rendering of a select is delegated to the OS/browser

I have tried

option[selected='selected'] { font-weight: bold; color: red; }

option:checked ... do not apply to select

Even applying a style inline don’t work ... as is a list of checkboxes could ... you for sure going to review your design ...

Comment: hmmm, but the Bryce-Howitson's solution code works fine for me.

Comment: It will not work on all browser due to the fact that the standard state that how it is rendered is upon OS/browser implementation choice

It seem important to show it as a list of data within the page what will make css rules available